# Изменить курсив в EditText

Tags: android, xamarin, android-edittext

Проблема в очень некрасивом курсиве)

Я новичок, и думаю, что проблема в `EditText` или же в теме?

Как видно из скринов, есть 2 точки, но когда вводишь текст, они становятся полосками по размеру `EditText`.

Нужно их забрать, но как, не знаю.

Вот axml-файл

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputMsg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F8F6F6"
        android:textColor="@color/text_msg_input"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable ="@null"/>
```

и скрины

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в background
нужно задать

```
android:background="@null"
```